# String replace with wildcard

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `http://localhost:9000/category` that I want to replace with `category.html`, i.e. strip everything before `/category` and add `.html`.

But can't find a way to do this with str_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*\/(\S+)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1.html`.see demo .

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/43

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `parse_url` in this case:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$file  = $parts['path'].'.html';
```

Or something along that line. Experiment a bit with it.

Ismael Miguel suggested this shorter version, and I like it:

```
$file = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH).'.html';
```

Comment: Btw, to sorten your answer, you can use `parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH).'.html';`.

Comment: I added a space. And your last tip is a good one. To be honest I have always disliked regular expressions. They work, but why? Every time I need to change one, I struggle to understand what it does and how I can make it do what I want. I try to avoid them when possible, and your short version is an excellent alternative.

Comment: Regex is the necessary evil that we sometimes depend on when we need something complex. In this case, a regex is a waste of computer power. But sometimes isn't bad to use regex when we need to extend the behavior after. Avinash Raj's regex is simple enough to be eye catching. There are "crimes" that we must commit with regex, sometimes (like a loose email validation). I just think we must separate each situation. In this case, this is the proper way to do it. Yes, I misread it at first, but this is the right way. PHP has a built-in function for it, just use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of `str_replace`

Regex:

```
.*\/(.+)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1.html
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bN3eL0/1)

```
$input = "http://localhost:9000/category";
echo preg_replace("~.*/(.+)~", '$1.html', $input)
```

Output:

```
category.html
```

Comment: it should be like `~.*/([^/]+)[/]?~` instead, just in case the op wants to use `http://localhost:9000/test/category/q/` too. In case he doesn't, your regex is really working great!

Comment: Actually, it would, but the OP didn't said anything about ending with `/`. I posted an answer assuming that the input will neven end with `/`, but I'm changing it to solve that 'issue'.

Answer (score 0):

A solution **without** regex:

```php
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost:9000/category';
    echo @end(explode('/',$url)).'.html';
?>
```

This splits the string and gets the last part, and appends `.html`.

Note that this **won't** work if the input ends with `/` (e.g.: `$url = 'http://localhost:9000/category/';`)

Also note that this relies on non-standard behavior and can be easily changed, this was just made as a one-liner. You can make `$parts=explode([...]); echo end($parts).'.html';` instead.

If the input ends with `/` occasionally, we can do like this, to avoid problems:

```php
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost:9000/category/';
    echo @end(explode('/',rtrim($url,'/'))).'.html';
?>
```